# Inserting into a MySQL table with an auto-increment column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, perl

I'm trying to insert data into my database with a Perl script, but there's something wrong with my code.

I previously created a table `annotations` with eight columns, and the first one is an auto incremented primary key. I also need the two last columns to be filled with `1` and `DB` on each row.

The errors I get when I launch my program in the prompt are :

> DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Incorrect integer value: 'NULL' for column 'id_anntion' at row 1 at C:\Users\Jean Baptiste\cours\Base de donnÚes\Dossier\programmes\remplissage_table_projet.pl line 25,  line 1.
>   Erreur insertion : Incorrect integer value: 'NULL' for column 'id_anntion' at row 1 at C:\Users\Jean Baptiste\cours\Base de donnÚes\Dossier\programmes\remplissage_table_projet.pl line 25,  line 1.

And this is the code :

```
use DBI;
use strict;
use utf8;

use warnings;

my ($ligne, @tab);

# Connexion à la base de données
my $dbh = DBI->connect( "DBI:mysql:database=projet;host=localhost", "root", "" )
  or die "Erreur de connexion : " . DBI->errstr();


# Gestion de l'encodage UTF-8
$dbh->{'mysql_enable_utf8'} = 1;
$dbh->do('set names utf8');

# Préparation d'une requête pour l'insertion de valeurs dans la BDD
my $ins = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO annotations VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")
  or die "Probleme preparation : " . $dbh->errstr();

open( FILEIN, '<:encoding(utf8)', 'alsace_DB.csv' );
while ( $ligne = <FILEIN> ) {
    chomp($ligne);
    @tab = split( /;/, $ligne );
    $ins->execute("NULL", $tab[0], $tab[1], $tab[2], $tab[3], $tab[4], "1", "DB")
      or die "Erreur insertion : " . $ins->errstr();
}
close(FILEIN);

# Déconnexion de la base de données
$dbh->disconnect();
```

I know there's something to do with the `"NULL"` part but I can't tell what. And I think it's not the only problem.

Comment: `"NULL"` - is a string value. Try to use zero length string `""`. Or set the list of columns except for the first: `insert into annotations(column2, column3, ...) values ( seven ? ); execute(@tab[0..4],"1","DB")`

Comment: @Mike: I doubt if `""` will work, as it's still a string. The official ways to invoke autoincrementation are to pass `0`, or `undef` if the column is `NOT NULL`, or nothing at all by leaving the column out of the list.

Comment: I removed the phpMyAdmin tag for you since this doesn't seem related to that application.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to insert the *string* `"NULL"` into an *integer* column

If you want to override the autoincrement behaviour then use a number such as 100 here

If you want MySQL to generate the numbers, then use zero `0` or, if the column is `NOT NULL` then you can use `undef`

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I don't see extactly where I should put  undef. Could you tell me more ?

Comment: @J-bFiancette: In place of the `"NULL"` which I explained was wrong. Or you could use `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `undef` in perl for inserting default values in MySQL table. So, here you need to modify your line as:
`$ins->execute(undef, $tab[0], $tab[1], $tab[2], $tab[3], $tab[4], "1", "DB")
      or die "Erreur insertion : " . $ins->errstr();`

In this case, it will auto-increment the column.